# location.reload(true) in SagePay iframe reloads parent in IE10/11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, iframe, opayo

This issue may be a generic javascript / iframe issue but relates to SagePay's authorisation (low profile) page which uses

```
setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 2000);
```

to reload the page. When using IE10/11 the parent is reloaded or navigates to the iframe url.

This doesn't seem to happen in a asp.net web forms publicly hosted site using identical html, however, is happening in an internal MVC4 application.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, if this is still an issue. But I ran into an similar condition where calling `location.reload(true)`in an iframe refreshed the parent and loaded the content of the iframe into the browser.

I made some researches but couldn't find anything which would trigger this problem. I also created a test page with an iframe which reloads itself but there the refresh worked properly in IE 11. But for the case where IE has the problem described above I now use `location.href = location.href.replace(location.hash, '')` instead of `location.reload(true)` as a solution.

One limitation of this approach is that it doesn't force the browser to clear the cache of the page. I also did not test this in IE 10 yet but feel free to add a comment if it works there. I hope this helps.

Comment: spooky, you answered this 2+1/2 years later and I just started working on this code again this morning and I just started looking at this code again! It's an issue that pops up periodically so I will try your fix in the new code

Comment: Hey @Paul, it has been a while and I am curious how you ended up solving this problem.. any news?